# Copy formula across row incrementing sheet number, down column incrementing number by 2

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have information on four different sheets I would like to copy to this summary sheet.

I want to know how do I copy the formula across the row and down the column on this summary sheet(say this is sheet2) so I display that info here.

Right now I have

D4 set as 
`=INDIRECT("'Sheet" & COLUMN()-2&"'.D4")`

This let's me copy across the row, but how do I change this to allow copying the formula down the column to get it to auto-increment "A#" by 2?

```
               4                     5                  6                 7    
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   D | =SUM('Sheet4',a1) | =SUM('Sheet5',a1) | =SUM('Sheet6',a1) | =SUM('Sheet7',a1) |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And how do I copy the same formula down a column so I get (I am skipping ever other row of data on sheets 4 - 7)

```
               4                     5                  6                 7
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  D | =SUM('Sheet4',a2) | =SUM('Sheet5',a2) | =SUM('Sheet6',a2) | =SUM('Sheet7',a2) |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  E | =SUM('Sheet4',a4) | =SUM('Sheet5',a4) | =SUM('Sheet6',a4) | =SUM('Sheet7',a4) |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+    
  F | =SUM('Sheet4',a6) | =SUM('Sheet5',a6) | =SUM('Sheet6',a6) | =SUM('Sheet7',a6) |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  G | =SUM('Sheet7',a8) | =SUM('Sheet5',a8) | =SUM('Sheet6',a8) | =SUM('Sheet7',a8) |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: These formulas don’t work.  Please post either correct formulas or an English explanation of the result you want.

Comment: Please indent code or preformatted text by 4 spaces, or select it and press `Ctrl-K`. Thanks